# React Native navigator.geolocation is undefined

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

but when I evaluate navigator.geolocation, I get:

```
navigator.geolocation is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario since React Native version 0.60 the Geolocation module was migrated out of React Native Core. For more information follow [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation)

**Migrating from the core react-native module**

OLD :

```
navigator.geolocation.setRNConfiguration(config);
```

UPDATED :

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

Geolocation.setRNConfiguration(config);
```

For your problem use like this:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => console.log(info));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import Geolocation as a separate module after installing it:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
const locationConfig = {skipPermissionRequests:false,authorizationLevel:"whenInUse"}

Geolocation.setRNConfiguration(locationConfig);
```

Then you call Geolocation.getCurrentPosition